# Proving an equality associated with symmetric positive definite matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, positive-definite, symmetric-matrices

Let $Q$ be an $n \times n$ symmetric positive definite matrix, $\vec{a}, \vec{b} \in \Bbb R^n$ be two random vectors. Prove that $a^TQ(ba^T-ab^T)Qb$ is non-positive.

---

Since $Q$ has $n$ independent eigenvectors with positive eigenvalues, I've tried expressing $\vec{a}$ and $\vec{b}$ as linear combinations of those eigenvectors, but it didn't work out. Really appreciate any help.

Comment: Interestingly, $a^TQ(ba^T-ab^T)b$ (with the $Q$ near the right side of the original expression removed) is also non-positive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By Cauchy-Schwarz $$|\langle \sqrt{Q}b,\sqrt{Q}a\rangle|^2=|a^TQb|^2\le \langle \sqrt{Q}b,\sqrt{Q}b\rangle \langle \sqrt{Q}a,\sqrt{Q}a\rangle=b^TQba^TQa$$

Comment: Thank you. I didn't know that a symmetric positive definite matrix can be square-rooted.